Managing users that authenticate with OAuth2
I am learning to use OAuth2 in my Spring Boot application, following this tutorial. For managing authenticated users, I started with a simple solution that uses principal.getName() as unique ID of the user to store them in MongoDB.
@GetMapping("/user")
    public ResponseEntity<UserDTO> user (@AuthenticationPrincipal OAuth2User principal) {
        User user = userService.findOrCreateUser (principal);
        //...
    }

and
public User findOrCreateUser (OAuth2User principal) {
        String id = principal.getName ();
        //...
}

This works quite well - when users authenticate via Github, the principal object has a different value for getName() than when users authenticate via Google. In both cases, the principal object has a consistent getName() value when users log out and log in again. My question is whether OAuth2 guarantess a unique value for getName() across all possible OAuth2 authentication providers. I could not find any information about this. If not, what is the proper way of uniquely identifying users?
Before I came up with the solution above, I tried to implement the "proper" way, but in the section "How to Add a Local User Database", the tutorial is quite vague:

Implement and expose OAuth2UserService to call the Authorization Server as well as your database. Your implementation can delegate to the default implementation, which will do the heavy lifting of calling the Authorization Server. Your implementation should return something that extends your custom User object and implements OAuth2User.

I tried the solution below, storing the OAuth2User object with each user. However, when User objects are read from MongoDB, there is an exception because no suitable constructor can be found (although the constructor has parameters for all fields of the class).
public class User implements OAuth2User {
    private final String id;
    private final OAuth2User principal;

Any help is appreciated, including pointers to further documentation.

There is no uniqueness guarantee across all OAuth providers for principal.getName().
To ensure uniqueness, you can do something similar to what Auth0 does when federating users across multiple providers. You could structure the ID as ${provider_name)|${sub} So if a user logs in via Google, their ID would be something like google|123456789012345678901
This gurantees uniquness because the sub claim is a standard (registered) claim that is guranteed to be unique identifier within each provider. Also, the subclaim is guranteed to be existing in any OIDC id_token, unlike other claims, like name, which might or might not exist.

Thank you for your response. I assume that provider_name correponds to the iss property, right?
Interestingly, the OAuth token from github. com does not provider either iss or sub.  The tokens generated from Google and Microsoft do, however. How would you deal with the token from Github?

Github doesn't implement OIDC. so you will have to handle it differently. you will use "id" instead of sub. Take a look at https://docs.github.com/en/rest/users/users?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-the-authenticated-user

The OpenID spec states that a user subject (sub claim) must be a unique identifier for a Provider. Most providers use UUIDs so subjects shouldn't conflict between providers, but to be strict, an identity identifier is the union of the "Issuer Identifier" (iss claim) and "resource owner subject within this issuer".
Use your own OpenID Provider as a user service if you need user management. Most on premise solutions (like Keycloak) and cloud offerings (Auth0, Amazon Cognito, etc.) can federate social identities ("login with ...") and expose a REST API to interact programmatically with stored users (manage roles for instance). Each also provides with features like UI theming or fancy login flows (remember-me, multi-factor authentication,"magic link", etc.)
